Laravel whereNotIn and NotIn condition does not work in foreach loop
I'm currently working with Laravel and trying to retrieve data where the status is not equal to zero. However, I need help with my query. The query works perfectly when I remove the whereNotIn condition.
$pr = ProductCategory::with('catproduct')
        ->where('id', $categoryDetials->id)
        ->get();
foreach ($pr as $Key=>$value) {
    foreach ($value->catproduct as $k=>$pro) {
        $productre = Product::where('id', $pro->product_id)
            ->whereNotIn('status', [0])
            ->first();
    }
}

Could anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here? Why does the whereNotIn condition cause my query to fail?

What about it isn't working? By the way, it looks like ProductCategory should be retrieving only 1 record, so you can optimize it with ProductCategory::with('catproduct')->find(categoryDetials->id) which will change $pr to be a single ProductCategory instead of a collection of 1

seems you are performing n+1 queries, why not eager load the nested relations such as with(['catproduct.product'  => fn ($query) => $query->whereNotIn('status', [0])])

aynber@Working on your suggestion
